# How to find all the color shapes in an image open CV python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have this image where I need to find the colored shapes in an image
[image]

I need the positions of these Colored shapes.

And I need to place this monkey on green triangle

[image]

My code is giving me the error
This code can only detect the black colour but it throws an error.

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# find all the  shapes in the image
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([15, 15, 15])
shapeMask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# find the contours in the mask
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print ("I found %d black shapes" % (len(cnts)))
cv2.imshow("Mask", shapeMask)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # draw the contour and show it
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What's that magical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In order to solve this problem. You need to do the follows:

1. Find the correct region of the green color in HSV space
2. Find the possible areas using contour detection
3. Sort the candidates by the size of areas
4. Find the bounding box of that area with max size
5. Compute the center of the bounding box
6. Fix the background of the monkey image.
7. Put the monkey image in the correct position.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

big_img = cv2.imread("color_img.jpg", 1)
monkey_img = cv2.imread("monkey.png", 1)

# define green value range
big_img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(big_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(big_img_hsv, (36, 0, 0), (70, 255,255))

# find the contours in the mask
img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# find the contour with max area
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]
# cv2.drawContours(big_img, [cnt], 0, (0,0,255), 3)

# Find the bounding box in that region
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
rect = (x, y), (x + w, y + h)
#cv2.rectangle(big_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

# Put the monkey to that region
img_height, img_width = monkey_img.shape[:2] 

# you like to put the monkey image to the center of this region
center_x = int(round(x + w / 2))
center_y = int(round(y + h / 2))
# so the starting point should be 
start_x = int(round(center_x - img_width / 2))
start_y = int(round(center_y - img_height / 2))

mask_img = np.where(monkey_img==[0,0,0])

# Grap information from original image
crop_from_original = big_img[start_y: start_y + img_height, start_x: start_x+img_width ] 

# put the pixel to monkey image
monkey_img[mask_img] =  crop_from_original[mask_img]

# put the monkey to the right image
big_img[start_y:start_y+img_height,start_x: start_x+img_width]=monkey_img

cv2.imshow("big_img", big_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Im getting an error in line number 33 TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method    @Howard

Comment: Hi, please see the updated version of code, and try it again?

Comment: open cv2 opencv-python==3.4.2.17